# How to sort points from a SpatialPoints object over a SpatialLines object according to line direction using R?

Tags: r, point, line, sp

I have a very **big dataset** of points (*SpatialPoints* object) over a line (*SpatialLines* object). I need to sort these points following the line direction.

**Note:** the number of points and coordinates that build the *SpatialLines* object are not necessarily the same of the *SpatialPoints* object.

I tried this ([How to make a SpatialLines object from undefined - but known - spatial sequence of points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778064/how-to-make-a-spatiallines-object-from-undefined-but-known-spatial-sequence/38798344#38798344)) using only the *SpatialPoints* object but the dataset is too big and my computer collapse (can't allocate all the data to memory).

An example using a **small dataset** sample:

```
# Load packages
library('sp')

# Define projection
epsg.32721 <- "+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Load data points
x <- c(794801.3, 795014.1, 795055.7, 795051.1, 795070.9, 794885.1, 795102.9, 795131.9, 795127.4, 795192.6, 795196.3, 795219.3, 795283.2, 795307.2, 795307.2, 795307.7, 795327.7, 795330.2, 795360.6, 795355.7, 794779.8)
y <- c(6194137, 6194211, 6194192, 6194192, 6194202, 6194210, 6194207, 6194217, 6194217, 6194231, 6194234, 6194275, 6194279, 6194713, 6194713, 6194714, 6194795, 6194335, 6194869, 6194865, 6194109)

# Create SpatialPoints object
spatialPointsObject <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Load data lines
x2 <- c(794779.8, 794790.6, 794795.7, 794801.3, 794810.2, 794815.9, 794828.5, 794838.2, 794846.4, 794844.0, 794850.5, 794858.6, 794869.3, 794877.9, 794886.3, 794895.5, 794904.8, 794914.9, 794926.2, 794938.3, 794948.1, 794958.7, 794969.6, 794978.4, 794987.1, 794999.1, 795008.2, 795017.6, 795025.5, 795032.2, 795045.8, 795055.7, 795064.3, 795073.5, 795083.1, 795093.2, 795103.4, 795112.6, 795122.2, 795131.9, 795142.3, 795152.4, 795162.3, 795168.3, 795178.9, 795187.8, 795196.3, 795200.5, 795207.6, 795213.0, 795219.3, 795268.8, 795275.3, 795283.2, 795289.9, 795308.4, 795313.5, 795320.6, 795330.2, 795344.0, 795344.7, 795350.1, 795354.6, 795367.8, 795372.8, 795377.6, 795367.6, 795367.5, 795377.5, 795372.5, 795372.5, 795367.6, 795367.6, 795367.6, 795367.5, 795367.5, 795367.5, 795372.6, 795372.7, 795377.6, 795377.6, 795377.6, 795377.5, 795377.5, 795372.5, 795372.6, 795368.5, 795363.0, 795362.5, 795362.1, 795363.1, 795307.2, 795315.1, 795318.8, 795325.1, 795325.9, 795328.8, 795334.4, 795331.9, 795334.2, 795338.3, 795346.1, 795353.1, 795365.9, 795373.4, 795389.3, 795388.9, 795390.4, 795394.7, 795400.2, 795410.4, 795411.0, 795416.5, 795413.8, 795422.3, 795423.4, 795424.4, 795427.2, 795427.0, 795431.5)    
y2 <- c(6194109, 6194113, 6194126, 6194137, 6194141, 6194142, 6194146, 6194155, 6194160, 6194183, 6194191, 6194197, 6194199, 6194204, 6194210, 6194215, 6194221, 6194227, 6194232, 6194227, 6194227, 6194227, 6194227, 6194222, 6194222, 6194215, 6194210, 6194211, 6194207, 6194206, 6194192, 6194192, 6194200, 6194202, 6194207, 6194207, 6194207, 6194212, 6194217, 6194217, 6194222, 6194227, 6194222, 6194222, 6194224, 6194228, 6194234, 6194242, 6194264, 6194269, 6194275, 6194270, 6194278, 6194279, 6194291, 6194294, 6194309, 6194317, 6194335, 6194350, 6194360, 6194369, 6194378, 6194393, 6194410, 6194426, 6194441, 6194452, 6194463, 6194475, 6194487, 6194497, 6194507, 6194517, 6194526, 6194536, 6194546, 6194549, 6194556, 6194567, 6194577, 6194588, 6194605, 6194616, 6194623, 6194637, 6194654, 6194671, 6194672, 6194683, 6194692, 6194713, 6194736, 6194744, 6194751, 6194765, 6194814, 6194819, 6194829, 6194836, 6194844, 6194850, 6194863, 6194874, 6194889, 6194903, 6194910, 6194922, 6194930, 6194940, 6194947, 6194956, 6194968, 6194980, 6194986, 6194997, 6195006, 6195016, 6195036, 6195051)

# Create SpatialLines object
spatialLinesObject <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(slinelist = list(Line(coords = cbind(x2,y2))), ID = "1")), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

# Plot SpatialPoints + SpatialLines + coordinates(SpatialLines)
plot(spatialLinesObject, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "SpatialPoints + SpatialLines + coordinates(SpatialLines)")
plot(SpatialPoints(coordinates(spatialLinesObject)), pch = 19, col = "black", add = TRUE, cex = 0.4)
plot(spatialPointsObject, col = "green", add = TRUE)
text(coordinates(spatialPointsObject), labels = seq_along(spatialPointsObject), cex = 0.7, pos = 3)
box()
```

I need to get a *SpatialPoints* object where the first point should be the **Point 21**, second point should be **Point 1**, third point should be **Point 6** and so on: [image: see this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could answer my question traveling through every line segment in the *SpatialLines* object and finding the intersected points from the *SpatialPoints* object. I made a function that is all explained by comments.

```
# Load packages
library('rgeos')
library('data.table')

# Vector norm
norm_vec <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))    

# OrderPointsAlongLine function
OrderPointsAlongLine <- function(spatialLinesObject, spatialPointsObject) {

  lineCoords = as.data.frame(coordinates(spatialLinesObject))
  lineCoordsLength = nrow(lineCoords)

  # Make a buffer 
  spatialPointsObjectBuffer = gBuffer(spgeom = spatialPointsObject, width = 1, byid = TRUE)

  # Aux list and data frame
  cellsAndDistances = list()
  cd = data.frame('cell' = NA, 'dist' = NA)

  # Go sequentially through every line segment in the SpatialLine object looking for which SpatialPoints are intersected
  for(i in 1:(lineCoordsLength - 1)) {

    # Unommented: show iteration number
    # cat(paste("\n iteration", i, sep = ""))

    # Line segment points
    p0 = lineCoords[i,]
    p1 = lineCoords[i+1,]

    # Build line segment
    SL = SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(Line(coords = rbind(p0,p1)), ID = paste(i, sep = ""))), proj4string = CRS(epsg.32721))

    # Find intersected points with line segment
    intersect = which(gIntersects(spgeom1 = spatialPointsObjectBuffer, spgeom2 = SL, byid = TRUE))

    # Points intersected
    p2 = spatialPointsObject[intersect,]

    p2Length = nrow(p2@coords)

    # If there is almost one point intersected
    if(p2Length != 0) {

      # If there are more than one intersected points
      for(j in 1:p2Length) {

        # Commented: show sub-iteration number
        # cat(paste("\n sub-iteration", j, sep = ""))

        cd[j,] = data.frame('cell' = intersect[j], 'dist' = norm_vec(coordinates(p2)[j,] - p0))

      }
    }

    # Order by distance
    data.table::setorder(cd, dist) 
    cellsAndDistances[[i]] = cd

  }

  # Bind list into one data farme
  cellsAndDistancesBind = do.call("rbind", cellsAndDistances)

  # Remove duplicated
  cellsAndDistancesBind <- cellsAndDistancesBind[-which(duplicated(cellsAndDistancesBind$cell)),]

  # Return
  return(cellsAndDistancesBind)

}

# Call function
orderedPoints <- OrderPointsAlongLine(spatialLinesObject = spatialLinesObject, spatialPointsObject = spatialPointsObject)

# Plots
plot(spatialLinesObject, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "", col = "green")
plot(spatialPointsObject[orderedPoints$cell,], add = TRUE, pch = 19, cex = 0.5)
text(coordinates(spatialPointsObject[orderedPoints$cell,]), labels = seq_along(spatialPointsObject[orderedPoints$cell,]), cex = 0.75, pos = 1)
```

[image: ordered points along line]

Improvements are welcome!

Comment: I think your function call should be `OrderPointsAlongLine` instead of `SortPointsAlongLine`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same function, but only using **Simple Features**. Although it is apparently less performant and takes almost twice the time.

```
library(sf)
OrderPointsAlongLineSF <- function(spatialLinesObject, spatialPointsObject) {

  lineCoords = data.table(st_coordinates(spatialLinesObject))
  lineCoordsLength = nrow(lineCoords)

  # Make a buffer 
  spatialPointsObjectBuffer = st_buffer(spatialPointsObject, dist = 1)

  # Aux list and data frame
  cellsAndDistances = vector("list", lineCoordsLength-1)
  cd = data.frame('cell' = NA, 'dist' = NA)

  # Go sequentially through every line segment in the SpatialLine object looking for which SpatialPoints are intersected
  for(i in 1:(lineCoordsLength - 1)) {
    # Line segment points
    p0 = lineCoords[i, c("X", "Y")]
    p1 = lineCoords[i+1, c("X", "Y")]


    SF <- st_as_sf(rbind(p0,p1), coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
      summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>%
      st_cast("LINESTRING") 
    SF$id = paste(i, sep = "")
    st_crs(SF) <- st_crs(spatialLinesObject)

    # Find intersected points with line segment
    intersect = which(st_intersects(spatialPointsObjectBuffer, SF, FALSE))

    # Points intersected
    p2 = spatialPointsObject[intersect,]

    p2Length = nrow(p2)

    # If there is almost one point intersected
    if (p2Length != 0) {
      # If there are more than one intersected points
      for(j in 1:p2Length) {
        cd[j,] = data.frame('cell' = intersect[j], 'dist' = norm_vec(st_coordinates(p2)[j,] - p0))
      }
    }

    # Order by distance
    data.table::setorder(cd, dist) 
    cellsAndDistances[[i]] = cd
  }

  # Bind list into one data farme
  cellsAndDistancesBind = do.call("rbind", cellsAndDistances)

  # Remove duplicated
  cellsAndDistancesBind <- cellsAndDistancesBind[-which(duplicated(cellsAndDistancesBind$cell)),]

  # Return
  return(cellsAndDistancesBind)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@SeGa's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287953/107424), To sf solution I would replace duplicates removal with

```
  # Remove duplicated
  cellsAndDistancesBind <- cellsAndDistancesBind[!duplicated(cellsAndDistancesBind$cell),]
```